# Invalidating OutputCache programmatically on UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, user-controls, outputcache

Is there any way of invalidating OutputCache on UserControl?
I've setup a partial caching on my site using UserControls and it's working fine.
I've set output cache like this in my user control:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

My user contrlol is located in `/UserControls/SomeAction.ascx`
So I've tried to invalidate it using this and it didn't work.:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/UserControls/SomeAction.ascx");
```

I also tried this approach:
I've set `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("MyCache",DateTime.Now);` inside Global.asax's `Application_Start` function, and `Response.AddCacheItemDependency("MyCache");` inside my user control's `Page_Load` function.
I've then tried to invalidate it by calling another function:

```
    private void InvalidateCache()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("MyCache", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

It still didn't work.

Is there any way to invalidate UserControl's cache programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Use usercontrol's [CachePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.cachepolicy.aspx) property to create a dependency on another cache key. For example,
in user control code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CachePolicy.Dependency = new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(null, 
        new string[] { "KeyForThisUserControl"  });
    ...
}
```

And else-where to invalidate user-control's cache, use

```
Cache["KeyForThisUserControl"] = DateTime.Now;
```

where Cache refers to current web application cache.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use your code. If I set this `CachePolicy.Dependency` inside my `Page_Load` event in my user control, my cache doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @ttkalec, not sure what is the issue? Have you tried creating the cache key before adding dependency on it? Also check `SupportsCaching` property otherwise that code may throw an exception. You may try adding `PartialCachingAttribute` to user control to enable caching (`OutCache` directive should have been doing the same). See cache policy doc for more details in using the policy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcachepolicy.aspx

Comment: Excellent solution. This worked for me. I could not find a way to get `RemoveOutputCacheItem` to work directly for UserControls (ascx).

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly your problem:

Make sure you set the cache `Location = "Server"` otherwise it will cache on the Clients machine and then your code

`HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/UserControls/SomeAction.ascx");`

Should work?

Comment: `Location=Server` is not supported in user controls. I get an error, and it stated so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are calling RemoveOutputCacheItem from the control itself, which would mean that the control is basically trying to remove itself from the cache...

Try calling `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/UserControls/SomeAction.ascx");` from another page.

Comment: I'm not calling `RemoveOutputCacheItem` from the control itself. It's on totally separate page.